# Is the a way to force Spark Aggregate / Reduce to "bubble-up"?

Tags: apache-spark

I tried both `aggregate` and `reduce` in Spark that produce large datasets. I noticed that part of the reduction was executed in my `driver`. According an MLLib blog, they have managed to implement the `bubbling`, ie. once workers have reduced each `task`/`partition` then move the reduction phase to a subset of workers until eventually this is delegated back to the driver.

In my use case, I have 580 partitions that don't have too many entries in common, ie. each partition size is 2GB but all partitions aggregated are also 2GBs. As the `driver` is delegating the reduction of partitions to the `driver` I get an OOME. Have I missed an API call that can do this or is the best way to force this behaviours by applying incremental `repartitioning` ?

Tnx

Comment: Can you post some code? Did you try increasing the driver's memory on the job configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`rdd.treeAggregate`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L979) that applies the reducer in a multi-leveled way, reducing the amount of data passed to the driver for final reduction.

It has been moved from mllib to Spark core on Spark 1.3.0. See [SPARK-5430](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5430)